# How can DRI 3 be enabled with AMDGPU-Pro?

Tags: xorg, amdgpu-pro

So I heard that enabling DRI 3 can help performance for GPU's. SO I want to enable it but safely.

This are the files I found:

```
ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
00-amdgpu.conf  10-amdgpu.conf  10-quirks.conf  10-radeon.conf  40-libinput.conf  70-wacom.conf
```

I suspect I should add some lines to `10-amdgpu.conf`

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "AMDGPU"
    Driver "amdgpu"
    Option "AccelMethod" "glamor"
    Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

[Source](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-amd-radeon-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

**Current** `10-amdgpu.conf`

```
Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "AMDgpu"
        MatchDriver "amdgpu"
        Driver "amdgpu"
EndSection
```

Comment: if the Xorg version is >= 1.18.3, when dri3 is default.

Comment: option "DRI" "3" just means highest DRI level to enable, `xdpyinfo | grep DRI`